# Exceptions in PHPunit doesn't work

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I want to test a if a method raises an exception. This is the method:

```
public function divide($a,$b)
{       
    try
    {
        if($b==0){
        throw new Exception('Divided by zero');
      }else{
        return $a/$b;       
      }
     }
     catch(exception $e)
     {
       return $e;
     }
}
```

and this is the test:

```
/**
* @expectedException Exception
*/
public function testException()
{
   //throw new Exception('Hello world');
   $this->calculator->divide(10,0));
}
```

If I check the code in the browser, the exception is raised correctly. But when I run the test, I always get a "Failed asserting that exception of type Exception is thrown" message. However, if I throw the exception inside the test method (uncomment the throw line), the test works fine.

Any clues?

I'm using phpunit 3.7, xampp 3.1, over windows XP.

Comment: You are catching the exception in the method so it won't bubble up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `Exception` is caught inside of the function. You don't let it bubble out. So the test won't assert it.

```
public function divide($a, $b)
{
    if ($b == 0) {
        throw new Exception('Divided by zero');
    } else {
        return $a / $b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I verified if the exception is launch inside a try/catch block, it won't be captured by phpunit, so I asumme I can't test handled exceptions. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeHernandez: If this question solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the question's score.

Comment: In the past, I was unable to have PHPUnit catch the default exceptions, but would report on user defined exceptions.  IE: expectedException Exception would not work, but expectedException MyExeception would.